# Python regexp for data of byte numbers

Tags: python, regex

How to make a regexp matching for a row of bytes?
For example how to check with regexp that binary data consists of (0-10 byte) characters?

`data = 0x00 0x05 0x02 0x00 0x03` ...  (not a string, binary data)

Comment: I know, I was just thinking whether can it be done with regexps or not. Didn't find such info in python docs.

Comment: @mac: Python strings are essentially byte arrays, and they can contain binary data, which regexes can match against just fine.

Comment: Could you post the Python `repr` of some data (e.g. `print repr(data[:50])`) that you have? It's not clear if you have binary data or a hex representation of such in a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to check that the string contains only characters between `chr(0)` and `chr(10)`, simply use

```
re.match('^[\0-\x0A]*$',data)
```

For Python3, you can do the same with byte strings:

```
re.match(b'^[\0-\x0A]*$',b'\x01\x02\x03\x04')
```

Answer (score 2):

This will match any code before <kbd>space</kbd>:

```
if re.search('[\0-\037]', line):
    # Contains binary data...
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "0-10 byte", but if you mean that you want to match only the byte values 0 to 10, then replace `\037` with `\012` in the above code.

Note that 0-10 aren't really the only codes that would suggest binary data; anything below `\040` or above `\0177` usually suggests binary data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want check if *all* characters in the given string are in the range `0x00` to `0x0B` (not inclusive), regex is way overkill. Try something like this:

```
>>> check_range = lambda x: ord(x) in set(range(0x00, 0x0B))
>>> s = '\x1\x2\x3\xA'
>>> s2 = 'abcde'

>>> print all(check_range(c) for c in s)
True
>>> print all(check_range(c) for c in s2)
False
>>>
```

Comment: I tested it with timeit module, short string s (5 symbols), million executions. Regexp wins (3.5x faster)

Comment: My own tests bear this out. I would delete this answer, but your comment is useful. With some optimization, I managed to bring it down to about 1.3x the speed of the regex version, but not below it.